# 2010 Ford Taurus glove compartment parts won't fit

Tags: ford, plastic

When I open the glove compartment there are 2 sticks that look like they should be connected to hold the door. But I didn't find a way to connect them. Are there any directions how these two things(holders) are supposed to be attached?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can someone look in their car how it is connected if they have the same car?